# Modifying CSS dynamically - Works in IE9, but not Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, background-color

I've got this function for changing the background color of a CSS class.

```
function changeBackgroundColor(className, value){
    var ss = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i=0; i<ss.length; i++) {
        var ss = document.styleSheets;
        var rules = ss[i].cssRules || ss[i].rules;
        for (var j=0; j<rules.length; j++) {
            if (rules[j].selectorText === className) {
                rules[j].style.backgroundColor = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And calling it with this,

```
changeBackgroundColor(".menuActive", "#fff");
```

It's working perfectly in IE9, but when testing in Chrome and firefox, it doesn't seem to work out. It seems like Chrome and Firefox doesn't find any classes or anything.
I'm a bit new to javascript, so if you could solve this or guide me in any way, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: Any reason you're defining `ss` twice, to be the same thing, in two different places? Plus, try using `document.styleSheets[i].rules[j].style.backgroundColor = value` instead of your rules array. Sneaky suspicion that you're modifying a copy of the rules array, and not the actual array.

Comment: why are you redefining `ss` in the body of your loop?

Comment: To be honest, i have no idea. This is pretty much a script found by a friend of mine. Turned out it worked, but only in IE. Just tried removing the redefining of the `ss`. Still works, so guess it wasn't neccesary redefining.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend a different approach instead of using `document.styleSheets`:

```
function changeBackgroundColor(className, value){
    var elements;
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'function') {
        // modern browsers
        elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    } else {
        // other browsers (IE)
        elements = document.querySelectorAll('.' + className);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor = value;
    }
}
```

Also, you're one small step away from a more generic function:

```
function changeStyle(className, styleName, value){
    var elements;
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'function') {
        // modern browsers
        elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    } else {
        // other browsers (IE)
        elements = document.querySelectorAll('.' + className);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style[styleName] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this script does somehow what I need. But it is selecting the html element with the class, and then giving that element a hardcoded style. What I need is to modify the class within the CSS document.

Comment: @JeppeUdesen can i ask why? i've never heard of anyone needing to do that before and i am curious

Comment: I'm making a one page template, and then I've set each menu point, (Home, Portfolio, Services etc), to be active as you scroll down. So basically when youre 500px and over, the Home menu will have an .activeClass, from 500-1000px, next menu will get the .activeClass. Now to visualize it for the user, I've set this activeClass to have a background-color. 

It all works fine, but here is where its getting tricky. I've made a customizer, so the buyer can easily customize fonts, colors etc. Check next post.

Comment: Problem is the `$(selector).css('background-color', '#fff')`, wont work, since it's getting hardcoded into the HTML element. Which means when you scroll down, the .activeClass will still have the same color as before, and not the one which the user chose. 

Kinda hard to explain, would be a lot easier showing. If possible to send priv messages.

Answer (score 0):

The rule interface supported by Internet Explorer is not the same as that supported by other browsers. There's no "selectorText" property of a rule object, for example.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/cssRule) is the Mozilla documentation for a `CSSRule` object.